# React, useState hook - should I ALWAYS prefer the update function instead of the object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

useState hook:

I've seen a recommendation to **always** prefer to use the update function instead of passing an object.

I know that when you depend on the previous state you should use it, but the recommendation here is to **always** prefer the update function no matter what.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCuYPiUIONs&t=1709s

Can someone explain me why?